# Redirect after a post request with data in react js / node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to send data to another component page after doing a post request to my node js server.

first component to redirect: (I cannot post all my code, it is to big

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/createVolume', requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.setState({
                        ansibleAnswer: data,
                        submitted: true
                    })
                    console.log(this.state.ansibleAnswer);
                });
.
.
.
// uderneeth my render

        } else if (this.state.loaded === true && this.state.submitted === true) {
            return (
                <Redirect to={{
                    pathname: '/Completed',
                    state: { name: this.state.name, result: this.state.ansibleAnswer }
                }}
                />
            );
```

new component after post request:

```
class Completed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: this.props.location.state.name,
            result: this.props.location.state.ansibleAnswer
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div>
                    <p>test successful</p>
                    <p>{this.state.result}</p>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Completed;
```

I get this error:

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

I understand that the data isn't saved in the state but I don't understand how I could save it (or wait) before sending the data to the other component.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
        class Completed extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    name: '',
                    result: ''
                };
            }

        /** When the Completed component does anything with the new props,
        * componentWillReceiveProps is called, with the next props as the argument */

        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

            /** Update  state**/

            if (nextProps.location.state.result !== 
            this.props.location.state.result) {
            this.setState({ 
                result:nextProps.location.state.result 
                });
            }

        }

            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Header />
                        <div>
                            <p>test successful</p>
                            <p>{this.state.result}</p>
                        </div>
                        <Footer />
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }


        export default Completed;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but I don't know why, the string is still empty.

Comment: Try to log props inside componentWillReceiveProps method, then check  "nextProps.location.state.ansibleAnswer"  has data or not

Comment: nextProps.location.state.ansibleAnswer is suppose to be nextProps.location.state.result...... Check your Redirect state props